# want to get one app session status in other app #Asp.Net web apps

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, iis

I have 2 web apps on Asp .Net framework deployed on IIS. I want to get app1 session timeout /signout status in app2.Is there any way to do it.
I dont have code of app1 just aspx files can be changed.

I have tried cmd ping command. But it always return me success packets as current user session expired but application is running.

Comment: Your requirement requires some degree of code modification in app1, which is difficult to achieve without code. For example, if two apps use the same database, you can create a table to store session state information. App1 can update this table when a session times out or the user logs out, and app2 can periodically check this table to determine status.